# Is public key and privately key determined by their respective intrinsic values?

Tags: public-key-encryption

When it comes to public keys and private keys, are they determined by their respective intrinsic values, or by who (the public vs myself) holds it? In other words, if I switch the two before their first use, will the system still work?

From what I've read, it seems to me that the two are exchangeable, until you give one to the public and remain one for yourself privately. I wonder if it matters which key you give out.

Thanks.

Comment: Your question seems to a bit too broad, considering attempting it, and if you get stuck come back with the error so that you can get useful answers.

Comment: @FluxCoder, this couldn't be narrowed down further I'm afraid my friend. This is a theoretical problem and the error only occurs in our heads so I can't provide one at this moment. Sorry.